# Service Account for creating/removing namespaces and add/remove ClusterRole Bindings

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-rbac

Can I create a service account for such specific things and no more.
I'm interested because I don't know how clustered roles will behave in this context.

- One(first) service account has the right to create/remove namespaces
- Create/remove ClusterRole Binding for another(second) account.

The idea is that I want to make developers only have access to certain namespaces.
These namespaces are created dynamically, so every time I create a namespace, I will be adding a RoleBinding to their(second) service account.

This is described in this article https://faun.pub/kubernetes-rbac-use-one-role-in-multiple-namespaces-d1d08bb08286
This I know and understand how to do.

**I don’t understand a little how to define a role for an account(first) that will only have the right to create/remove namespaces and create/remove ClusterRole Binding**

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks

Comment: Honestly I did not understand the question. What exactly do you need to get eventually? `Clusterrole` which is capable to `delete/create ns/clusterrolebinding`? Or anything else?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. If I say that my cluster role can only create and delete namespaces. Is it possible to make it so that the clustered role could not delete the system namespaces? I didn't find this in the documentation.

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for. Roles can be inherited. Thanks. https://travis.media/clusterrolebinding-with-service-account-all-namespaces/

Comment: You can post then the [answer on your own question and then accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I'm not sure what you mean by `inheritance`. As for `clusterrole` you can explicitly mention namespaces where this clusterrole will have permissions, but I don't remember there's an option to exclude it. + not clear what amount of accounts is used? 1 for developer and 1 for some automation tool? Does developer use service account or regular user with certificate authorization?